# msi installer error for c# project

Tags: c#, windows-installer

My program installation sometimes gives the following error in the installer log:

```
 `Failed to grab execution mutex. System error 258.`
```

Does anyone have any more information on what this is?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that you are trying to install or uninstall another MSI while installing your package.

If you need to install other packages, you can add them as prerequisites. This is done differently for each setup authoring tool. You cannot use custom actions for this, at least not in InstallExecuteSequence.

[_MSIExecute Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372909%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Summary: One Execute sequence per machine and one UI sequence per process.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm only installing one package (with uninstall previous version set to true) for an integration test. The sequence is uninstall all versions, install old version, install new version over the top.The second install fails, is there any chance it could be hanging onto the mutex?

Comment: Look in the log to see what triggers the error. What happens right before the error is shown?